# ColdFusion 2016: cfinclude dynamic template name; occasional error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Good day - 
My work group upgraded from CF10 to CF2016. We have finished 2 of the 3 servers that run the application behind a load balancer.

Since the two servers have been upgraded, we get an occasional (<<1%) error on `<cfinclude>` statements:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another  process

The included files are different each time, but they have the same characteristic:  the names are dynamically generated in the cfinclude tag. For example:

```
<cfinclude template="#fileManager.getFile('appl1')#">
```

where `#fileManager.getFile('appl1')#` simply returns a string path to a CFM file.  The file definitely exists, and it is not e.g. being modified by a programmer or any other (known) process. The files themselves are generally just simple index.cfm files in directories that haven't been touched in a year.

This only happens on dynamically named templates in `<cfinclude>`, never static template names.

Here are the cache settings on the server.  Please note that the settings are the same on the server that doesn't experience this problem (the CF10 server)

[image]

Any ideas what can cause this random, fleeting error?  I can not establish any pattern other than CF2016.

Comment: Just a Guess, but by any chance in   
Server Settings > Request Tuning what is your Maximum number of simultaneous Template requests set to ... maybe try increasing that?

Comment: Try turning on the trusted cache on the production server.

Comment: We can certainly try request tuning, but a "file is in use" doesn't seem to make much sense in that context. The settings for max template requests is the same on the CF10 and CF2016 servers (25) and the error is only happening on CF2016. Unfortunately we can't turn on trusted cache (and it's not enabled on CF10) because the template could change during the life of the server.

Comment: What other processes are running on the ColdFusion server that might be accessing these files? I'm thinking specifically that it could be anti-virus software scanning the files as they get created. Are the files stored locally on the server or on network storage? It could be latency while writing the files. Just thinking out loud here. It might be some other process not related to ColdFusion.

Comment: Great questions - they're stored locally.  They're static .cfm files so nothing is modifying them, and they haven't been modified in years in some cases. I have not thought of virus software accessing the files though it seems like CF should be accessing the compiled template class and not the raw .cfm file (which it would only check for existence and not dynamically compile every time).  There are some semi-related issues with CF2016 SP2 that we are hoping mitigate this problem.  Still no occurrences in CF10.

Comment: Have you looked into your `fileManager.getFile` code? The error may well lie inside there, not in the actual included template.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes, it returns a valid string to a valid filename. It simply concatenates its one argument into a valid file path. The value of the argument, base path, and result path are available to us in the cfcatch and error email that we send. In these cases, the failing cfm files are ones that are <cfinclude>d thousands of times a day, almost all without error.